# Mysql add value on beginning and end of current value?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

As of now I got bunch of data that I need to modify.

Best example of my objective is to add a value to beginning and end of the current value for specific column

As if now I have, column of `tagline`

[image]

What I need to do is to add `<h1>` in the beginning and `</h1>` in the end of the current value.

The output will be `<h1>Full Process Microbiological Analysis</h1>`

This is applicable only where `id` `NOT IN 1 - 17`

Can I do this? The data is pretty huge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the following update statement:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET tagline = CONCAT('<h1>', tagline, '</h1>')
WHERE id < 1 OR id > 17;
```

We could just use `WHERE id > 17` assuming `id` would never have a zero or negative value.